# Vermicompost cockroaches

Tags: vermicomposting, manure

I have a nice garden which I have made using vermicompost. Plus I have used cow dung manure. I get a lot of flying cockroaches in that. How to get rid of this.

Comment: Could you please take pictures of these flying cockroaches?  Get pictures of any larvae or any insect in your compost.  Usually insects hatch and leave the area...but I don't know flying cockroaches.  I know the ones in Hawaii and Japan, big but no flying.

Answer (score 3):

You could try sprinkling food grade diatomaceous earth around the garden area where they frequent, but it requires reapplication once it gets wet.  It will desiccate the insect's exoskeleton (it doesn't discriminate the good from the bad).  Roaches tend to clean themselves frequently so they should get it on them.

I would mix in a ratio of powdered sugar or cocoa powder (between 1:3 to 1:1) and place bait in containers or LIGHTLY sprinkle areas that they frequent that are dry like near bricks and stones and other hiding places that they go to.  Other than that you'd have to go with a commercial product like the baits that use boric acid or another chemical or skip the dung if the roaches continue to be troublesome.  If there is a food source then they will find it.

Good Luck.